# Connect azure to external mqtt broker

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I have a device which acts as a MQTT-Broker and need to retrieve the data.
**What is the basic concept to subscribe to an external MQTT-Broker with the azure cloud and receive the data**.
All the information I found was mentioning the IoT-HUB and described the Azure Cloud as Broker. I didn't find any Information on how the Azure Cloud could act as client and subscribe to an external MQTT-Broker. Is the IoT-HUB not the correct tool but are there maybe App-Servieces or other options?
Context: Three topics with message frequency adjustable between 60s and <0,1s. Devices don't necessarily have to be managed within the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if you can get Azure IoT Hub to act as a client, but you can probably make your local device broker set up what is known as a bridge to Azure.

Bridging is part of the MQTT spec and it allows brokers to share messages on a configured set of topics with a remote broker.

How you do that will depend on what broker you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Unfortunately changes on the device are only possible through firmware updates by the supplier, so this option is out of reach.